# How to get listview item click count in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a Listview with some data.I want to get the number of click counts of the each listview item.Based on the click count i want to re arrange the Listview items please any one help me with some code

Comment: from where you get the listview data ??

Comment: I am getting listview data from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest answer :

add a new field to the database table you are retrieving the data from to hold the number of clicks  an item have for example name it `rank` .

when you want to retrieve the data append the `order by rank DESC` to your query .
this way your list will display the  items by their  rank i.e (the top ranked item will be displayed at the top of the list and so on... )

and each time the user click an item increment the rank of that item by updating the rank field .

in case you want to reorder the list after each click use the `cursor.requery()` method

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Java developer, but I doubt that by default such data are stored. Probalby, you should catch the item click event, store in some kind of array the id (index?) of the item and click count. Then, rearrange the list.

Comment: When a user click on an item, increase the click count by one. You have to store somewhere the click count, perhaps, a hashmap varianble.